# How to get shell mode to properly handle my PS1, which involves user-defined function calls?

Tags: shell, shell-mode

My bash_profile includes a couple functions to build the prompt. This is a super-simplified version, which I'm using to try to debug the problem with:

```
custom_git_function () {
  echo "git"
}

build_custom_prompt() {
  export PS1="\u:\W \$(custom_git_function) >"
}

build_custom_prompt
```

When I run shell mode in emacs, it seems to have access to `build_custom_prompt`, but not `custom_git_function`.

```
bash: custom_git_function: command not found
```

What's a clean way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables or functions defined in `.bash_profile` are loaded by login shells, and aren't available to programs started via your window manager. `.bashrc`, on the other hand, is run anytime you open a shell, include Emacs shell-mode. So if you move your function definition to `.bashrc` you should be able to see it from inside Emacs.

Usually, your login shell `.bash_profile` will include something like:

```
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

This will source everything in `.bashrc`, so anything in `.bashrc` gets loaded by login shells as well.